# Execution fail task ':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:processDebugGoogleServices'. No matching client found for package 'capacitor.android.plugins'

Tags: android, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

Error while building the app in studio.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekjWx.png)

Answer (score 0):

add google-services.json file in android/app and android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugin

edit package name in android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugin/menifests/AndroidManifest.xml and android/app/build.gradle

package must same as in services.json file.

Note - In gradle u need to change applicationId.

Answer (score 0):

open the manifest file in "capacitor-cordova-android-plugins" folder in android studio
replace "capacitor.android.plugins" with your app package name(like io.ionic.starter)